# Using SQL SELECT and COUNT together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has the following fields:

> Name | Category | Description

I want to select all categories and display them like:

> Category | Category Count

So how would I do a

```
SELECT Category FROM MyTable 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Category)
```

but have the count show the specific count for that row?

Comment: I was going to post, but this one is just too basic. Boogada, research the GROUP BY clause, it should give you what you need.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(Category) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is other example without group by function

Select category, count(category) over () from MyTable